# Menu com rolagem horizontal estilo touch screen (clicar e arrastar) em PCs

Tags: html, css, rolamento, touch, navegação

Utilizando como base o menu abaixo, é possível torná-lo deslizante como em celulares (sem ser necessário utilizar a barra de rolagem, apenas com clicar e arrastar)?

```css
ul.marcadores {white-space:nowrap; overflow-x:auto; background-color:#2D2D2D; width:300px}
ul.marcadores li {display:inline-block; float:none; margin:10px; padding:4px}
ul.marcadores li:hover {border-bottom:1px solid #FFFFFF; padding-bottom:1px}
ul.marcadores a {color:#FFFFFF; font-size:12px; font-family:Open Sans; text-transform:uppercase; font-weight:bold; text-decoration:none}
```

```html
<ul class='marcadores'>
<li><a href='#'>Link 0</a></li>
<li><a href='#'>Link 1</a></li>
<li><a href='#'>Link 2</a></li>
<li><a href='#'>Link 3</a></li>
<li><a href='#'>Link 4</a></li>
<li><a href='#'>Link 5</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sim, mas pra isso você vai precisar de um conhecimento de javascript, você pode usar o jQuery.

Nesse link tem toda a documentação da Draggable que é o que você precisa utilizar
https://jqueryui.com/draggable/

O primeiro exemplo mostrado na pagina inicial é parecido com o que você precisa, no seu caso é bloquear o movimento no eixo Y, permitindo o usuário fazer a movimentação apenas no eixo X. Dei uma modificada no código para melhor exemplificar.

```js
$( function() {
    $( "#draggable" ).draggable({
     containment: 'parent'
     });
});
```

```css
  .divPai{
    width: 100%;
    height: 150px;
    background: black;
  }
  
  #draggable { 
    width: 150px; 
    height: 150px; 
    background: red
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div class="divPai">
  <div id="draggable">
    <p>Drag me around</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Funcionou, @Pedro Junior! Só fiquei na dúvida de como bloquear o movimento no eixo Y, mas de resto, é o que eu estava precisando! Obrigado! Vou continuar na pesquisa aqui do material!

Comment: Então, você pode fazer igual eu fiz no exemplo, na divPai você seta uma altura, e no filho a mesma altura, no seu caso crie uma div pai, e a tag ul será a filha, e vc pode colocar a opção *containment: 'parent'*, o que fará filha movimentar dentro do pai